# FFMPEG naming conventions

Tags: windows-7, naming-conventions, ffmpeg

I am trying to see what the naming conventions are for FFMPEG. I am trying to take a video file and slice it up into images. I have it currently set to label them from 0 counting up, but was wondering if I could use the date and time instead of just a numerical representation.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Your question requires more info. What date and time? The system date and time of the system date and the time (position) in the video at which the still occurs. Are you extracting one frame per second? Remember that your file names will get crazy confusing if you extract each frame to a file.

Comment: Apologies for being vague. At the moment if I have a 30 second video then I get images labeled from 1.jpg to 30.jpg. What I would like to do is get the current system time to display if possible. so the same video may look like 06-13-2011-11-01-21.jpg to 06-13-2011-11-01-51.jpg

Comment: As far as naming, on W7, ffmpeg.exe wants the 8.3 format for both the input file and output file.  In a cmd window, dir /x will give you the 8.3 directory names and file names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ffmpeg will not do this**

ffmpeg is only going to name decoded frames based on their index.

However, you could probably write a short shell script to take a set of files named 1-30.jpg and change their names to current-time+1-30.jpg.  Not as direct, but not bad.

Comment: This is a simple solution that I should've thought of. This will do perfectly fine for now. Thank you very much